# expression type of list[equals] does not conform to expected type seq[either[string,int]]

Tags: scala

```
def convert(list: List[String]): Seq[Either[String, Int]] = list match {
      case head :: Nil => Right(head.toInt) :: Nil;
      case head :: tail => Right(head.toInt) :: convert(tail) :: Nil;
}

print(convert(List("3", "4", "55")))
```

I need a seq of either, but it transforms into a list[equlals] and i dont know what to do.

Comment: What is the use of `Left[String]` ?

Comment: It will be in the catch section if convertion goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the `List[String]` into `Seq[Either[String,Int]]`.

```
val input = List("1", "2", "testString")
//input: List[String] = List(1, 2, testString)
```

Conversion :

```
import scala.util.Try
val output: Seq[Either[String,Int]] =
 input.map(ele => Try(Right(ele.toInt)).getOrElse(Left(ele))).toSeq
//output: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left(testString))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
def convert(list: List[String]): Seq[Either[String, Int]] = list match {
      case head :: Nil => Right(head.toInt) +: Seq.empty;
      case head :: tail => Right(head.toInt) +: convert(tail);
}
```

Comment: It does not instantiate any `Left` anywhere. With input `convert(List("42", "nope"))` it produces the exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "nope"`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I know, read the comments on the question pls, i answered it.

Answer (score 0):

I like Rumeshs solution much, but if you prefer the pattern matching style:

```
def convert (list: List [String]): List [Either [String, Int]] = list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: tail => if (head.matches ("[0-9]+"))
        Right (head.toInt) :: convert (tail) else
        Left (head) +: convert (tail)
}

convert (List("3", "four", "55"))
// res304: List[scala.util.Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(3), Left(four), Right(55))

convert (List("3", "4", "55"))
// res305: List[scala.util.Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(3), Right(4), Right(55))
```

Tranforming it to Seq in the end is easy

```
convert (List("3", "4", "55")).toSeq
```

or use your own approach with +: , which will however return a List, since a List is a Seq, but it misses on failing .toInt calls.

I didn't test it - maybe this solution is faster than the Try{} approach, maybe slower, probably depending on how often the matching to an int fails.

Rumesh points out, that list.map works concurrently, so here is the Pattern matching in the String sense for his approach:

```
List("3", "four", "55") .map (ele => 
    if (ele.matches ("[0-9]+")) Right (ele.toInt) else (Left(ele))).toSeq
// res307: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(3), Left(four), Right(55))

List("3", "4", "55") .map (ele => 
    if (ele.matches ("[0-9]+")) Right (ele.toInt) else (Left(ele))).toSeq
// res308: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(3), Right(4), Right(55))
```

Comment: Your `@tailrecursive` function works sequentially, if you use list map then, it convert each element concurrently .